# Why throw the same Exception and do nothing with Log result?

Tags: java, exception, error-logging

At work a goal of mine is to be more involved in code reviews since I went to school for computer science and studied theory, etc. My coworkers all have picked up java through courses supplied from work, and just program to get an end product, not always in the most efficient way.

Anyways, we have a class that for our programs to access the sql database. Each method, throws a DataSourceException. With in that method there is also a try catch finally to handle the SQLException. This line is what intrigues me.

```
catch (Exception ex) {
      final String METHOD_NAME = "prepare";
      Log.log(MyClass.class, METHOD_NAME, ex);
      throw new DataSourceException(ex);
}
```

Why throw another DataSourceException if the method signature throws it? The result of the log isn't thrown. Meaning we do nothing with the line that contains Log.log : it essentially creates an object and never does anything with it? Should that be passed as the DataSourceException parameter. Sorry if this is a repeat.

TL;DR is the above code an anti pattern?

Comment: It logs all exceptions and maps them to DataSourceException so that the caller only has to care for one type. Looks fine to me at first glance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"never does anything with it"*? What do you think `log()` does? Perhaps it writes a log entry to a log file (if enabled)? That is *something*.

Comment: Fair enough, it didn't make sense to me at first. But what about the 3rd line? I'm not sure the method does anything with that result. log() returns an object that it does nothing with.

Comment: In the actual code, you don't catch DataSourceException  to throw a new DataSourceException . You catch Exception to throw a new DataSourceException

Comment: it rethrows using new exception. IMO a better approach would be to not catch any exception, and wherever dataSourceException is being caught, to the catch all and log, do whatever you need.. Because it is a lot of unnecessary catching and rethrowing for no reason.

Comment: I expect Log to accept a throwable (ex),  log the exception and then return the exception, so you can get a oneliner like this `throw new DataSourceException(Log.log(...,ex))`. But we can't know for sure, since we don't know the content of the log function.

Comment: @NickL would showing a code snippet help? The log does accept the exception. It get's the method name and calling class. However, it just returns all of that in a throwable Object (Calling class,methodName, and the original throwable. I'm just confused because IntelliJ gives me a "Result of Log not thrown" Warning. Which means its result isn't being used.. right?

Comment: BTW, it's bad practice to catch just `Exception`. One should catch the specific checked exceptions.

Comment: @kmud7 so the log function adds information to the exception, and returns it so you can rethrow it. The snippet shows how you could use this in practice, which as you are saying, is not used like that in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's intended to log exceptions, and then rethrow them so that someones code has to actually handle them.

Comment: But the log() returns a throwable object back, should that be the object passed as the parameter?

Comment: Without knowing the contents of the log function, I would expect log can throw it's own errors.  Ideally the developer using these functions would want to see their errors first.  Although some laughs are had when the error handler errors.